# AWS Elastic Beanstalk External DNS Not Routing Properly

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

It's been a while since I've done this, but I believe I've done everything correctly.

Here's what I've got setup;

- Elastic Beanstalk Environment - big-ugly-aws-url.com
- DNS at Registrar
- - CNAME setup for something.example.com to point to big-ugly-aws-url.com
- AWS Route53
- - Setup Hosted Zone for example.com
- - - Added A Record to point to Alias > Elastic Beanstalk Environment > The one that is set up

What is odd is that all of these combinations works;

- 1.2.3.4 (IP address of Elastic Beanstalk Environment)
- 1.2.3.5 (IP address of EC2 Instance behind the scenes)
- 1.2.3.5.a.b.c (Hostname of EC2 Instance behind the scenes)
- big-ugly-aws-url.com

Yet the friendly version doesn't work;

- something.example.com

Although, when I ping something.example.com, this successfully resolves to the CNAME of big-ugly-aws-url.com.

I can't see any reason why this wouldn't be working. To test this I've even configured the Security Group on the EC2 instance behind the Elastic Beanstalk environment to allow inbound traffic from anywhere 0.0.0.0/0 yet it's still not working.

Ideas?

Comment: You don't require AWS Route53 setup. Just set CName in your domain registrar and you are done. Remove Route 53 setup and then try again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Grrr, flaming Windows DNS Caching.....

```
ipconfig /flushdns
```

Solved the problem... *rolls eyes*